# Not getting ag-grid in routed html page

Tags: html, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to get ag-grid on my HTML page **new.html** which will be loaded into the view upon a click on **old.html** page. **new.html** will be loaded through angular root.

**old.html** is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="ag-grid.js"></script>
    <script>
        var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);
        module.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/route1', {
                    controller: 'myCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'new.html'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }]);
        module.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
                var gridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: [
                        {headerName: 'Name', field: 'name'},
                        {headerName: 'Role', field: 'role'}
                    ],
                    rowData: [
                        {name: 'Niall', role: 'Developer'},
                        {name: 'Eamon', role: 'Manager'},
                        {name: 'Brian', role: 'Musician'},
                        {name: 'Kevin', role: 'Manager'}
                    ]
                };
                new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div> 
        <a href="#/route1" role="button">Route</a> 
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

**new.html** is as follows:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
</body>
```

when I execute **old.html** separately keeping the **myCtrl** controller code inside script tag and a function in **new.html**, it works well and the grid is displayed along with the data population. But in the routed view grid is not getting displayed.
I want the grid to be displayed upon the click of link present in **old.html**

Please help me fixing this issue. Thanks.